# Easy one: "Posts" are to forums as ? are to chats

Tags: naming-conventions

Im making a chat in rails. How do you call each "line item"? In a forum they are called posts.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "messages"?

Comment: I believe the IRC spec calls them that.